# Magento admin panel missing

Tags: javascript, magento

We have been happliy using magento for a few months, but have since found this issue that we cannot track to a date or change on the system and are at a loss how to fix.

Our admin panel has lost a div called "mass action", so now we have no way to mass select

See attached screenshot, our dev box has the items, but live server has lost it.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31039169/screenshot-admin.jpg

All core js files unedited.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Did you have any phtml differences ? or xml config changes? try using a compare tool like winmerge.

Comment: thanks boruch - will have a look with winmerge and report back

Comment: This was caused with a grid.phtml conflict between competing extensions (custom grid & custom statuses) - removed the offending extension and contacted the developer to fix